# relative path problem in firefox?

Tags: asp.net, firefox

I am using the javascript to popup a calendar when user click on calendar icon.
So here I am using like `../calendar/calendar.html?datetime=` to trigger the calendar.html.

But when I try to test it in IE its working but not in Firefox(It's not getting the correct url path). How to solve this issue. Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Does your page use any `<base />` tags?

Comment: Yes it does uses base tag like this in the header<base href="http://dev.net.com/virtualdirectoryname/abc.aspx">

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#edef-BASE), the `href` attribute of the `<base>` element must be an absolute URI.  I am guessing you are also using a relative path here, which IE (among other browsers) deems acceptable.

Comment: So how to solve this issue, I am kind of confused.Please let me know.Thanks

Comment: I can't change the base url to absolute url. It will take lot of changes. Any best workaround for this one.

Comment: Could you just remove the base tag?

Comment: @user594591 If it will "take a lot of changes" to modify one base tag, then you have other problems.  Good luck.